# Bigint operator >> overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, bigint

Here is my code for my operator>> overload. It is supposed to take the numbers up to a semicolon and put them into a bigint.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, bigint& bi) {

    int i = 0;
    char ch;
    char temp[SIZE];

    // grabs the first character in the file
    is >> ch;
    temp[i] = ch;
    ++i;

    // while loop grabs the rest of the characters
    // up to the semicolon
    while(ch != ';') {
        is >> ch;
        temp[i] = ch;
        ++i;
    }

    // temp is stored in the bigint ref
    bi = bigint(temp);

    return is;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I run it, it gives me extra output. For example: when I type in "34;" as the input, the resulting bigint will be "3411". Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not null-terminating your string `temp`. Add this:

```
temp[i - 1] = '\0';
bi = bigint(temp);
```

Note the `-1` will remove the semicolon that you probably don't need either. If you want to keep the semicolon there for whatever reason, change it to `temp[i]`.

You should also add a check to your while loop to make sure you don't overflow your buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

You are guaranteeing a semicolon is in `temp` at the end. The semicolon is probably messing up whatever parsing `bigint` is doing with that string. Change the loop to test for the semicolon before inserting it into `temp`:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, bigint& bi)
{
    char temp[SIZE] = {}; // zero out the array so the end is null terminated
    char c;

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE-1 && is >> c && c != ';'; ++i)
    {
        temp[i] = c;
    }

    bi = bigint(temp);
    return is;
}
```